# How to cleanly kill a stuck docker service?

Tags: centos, docker, xfs

Working with a Centos7 with 3.10 kernel, docker 19.03.12.

Eventually, one of the docker images got full and wrote the entire `/var/` mount to 100%, crashing both the docker service and the running containers.

Now there are 2 zombie process left that I can't kill (with `kill -9` or `killall`:

```
ps axjf | grep docker
    1 30215 30215 30215 ?           -1 Ds       0   0:00 [docker-entrypoi]
    1 32063 32063 32063 ?           -1 Zsl      0   0:00 [dockerd] <defunct>
```

Meanwhile, on `/var/log/messages` I'm getting:

```
kernel: XFS (dm-8): Failing async write on buffer block 0xb78170. Retrying async write.
kernel: XFS (dm-8): metadata I/O error: block 0xb78170 ("xfs_buf_iodone_callback_error") error 28 numblks 8
```

where it seems that some IO is still trying to write some data. This seems to be repeating on an infinite cycle, and I'm not sure how to stop it.

`du -sh` and `ls -al` hangs quickly when inspecting the `/var/lib/docker` files.

Additionally, `service docker stop/start` also hangs; `top` reports very high load/wait times (around `23` for a 4 core machine).

**My question:** without rebooting the machine, what would the best way to cleanly stop the `xfs` writes, kill the zombie processes and restart the services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free up some disk space.

The error reported by the kernel messages you posted is 28, "No space left on device".

Comment: This didn't change after freeing up the /var. My guess is that the docker service doesn't expand the virtual drive, which it can't due to being stuck? And I can't seem to restart the service due to unresponsive systemctl calls.

Comment: @Nutle You didn't provide any information about how you set up Docker storage, nor about your XFS filesystem.

Comment: I don't know the details, since I'm not the one who set it up. This is a standard general purpose machine, with ``docker-ce`` installed with everything by default. What additional info should I provide? The guess about the docker drive comes from the observation, that ``ls -al`` and ``du -sh`` freezes when looking at ``/var/lib/docker/.../devicemapper`` folder - my guess is that this is where the container data is stored.

Comment: @Nutle Devicemapper? That's not a good sign. That was never a production quality storage driver and was never recommended for anything but development or testing, and it isn't very good at those either. I suspect you're going to be rebuilding this box before it's over. Anyway, you could provide information about the Docker storage configuration, filesystems present on the machine (e.g. df), xfs_info, and anything else that might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm not an expert here, but I recalling hearing about CentOS7 overall being too old (kernel-wise) for proper volume support, among other things, and that it would be better to move to Debian or similar for docker. Maybe this is a related issue. If this is gonna result in a rebuild, maybe it's also best to consider moving to Debian (or some other later kernel) that would be more suitable for production?

Comment: @Nutle CentOS 7 is perfectly fine. All the relevant kernel bits have been backported. (And I'd worry about your sanity if you went to Debian for anything.) You should provide the information I requested.

Comment: Rebooting the machine seems to have fixed it (xfs and docker were able to recover), took at least 4 hours to boot up again for some reason. This seems like the issue that could easily come up again - instead of a dirty script to monitor and clean the space, is there an alternative configuration for docker's filesystem? You mentioned the use of ``devicemapper`` - how would you advice changing it? I understand that this is beyond the scope for this post, but any hint towards the right direction would really help. Will accept your answer since technically it was the main issue.

Comment: From the ``xfs_info`` on ``/var`` mount, it seems that it is set to ``type=0``, i.e.,  ``naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0``. Does this imply that the ``overlay2`` setup wouldn't work, [as per this discussion](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1475625)?

Comment: @Nutle Yes, overlay2 is what you should be using, and you should also have a long chat with whoever chose the non-default ftype=0 on your XFS filesystem, because you'll have to reformat that too.